# Why is my app terminating?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a simple server client code to exchange messages, but my app terminates when I try running client.Following is my code for client:

```
public class Client extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void SMessage() throws IOException {


        EditText ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
        String ipadd, edttxt, output;
        PrintStream ps = null;
        Intent i;
        Scanner sc = null;
        ipadd = ip.getText().toString();
        Socket s = null;
        s = new Socket(ipadd,1234);
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), new_activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        ScrollView Rl = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        sc = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_txt);
        edttxt = et.getText().toString();
        ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(edttxt);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(edttxt);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tv1.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_msg));

        }
        tv1.setGravity(View.FOCUS_LEFT);
        Rl.addView(tv1);

        output = sc.nextLine();
        if (output.equals("END")) {
            s.close();
            return;
        }
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(output);
        tv2.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tv2.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_msg));

        }
        tv2.setGravity(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        Rl.addView(tv2);


    }

}
```

Log when app terminates:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
                  Process: com.example.devanshi.testapp, PID: 2325
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:33)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:33)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                      at com.example.devanshi.testapp.Client.SMessage(Client.java:27)
                      at com.example.devanshi.testapp.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:60)
```

Main Activity when i call client is as follows:

```
public void client(View view)  {
        final Client c = new Client();
        Thread t=new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                try {
                    c.SMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        t.start();

    }
```

I would like to know where did I go wrong and how can I solve it. 
Thanks in advance for your response. :)

Comment: you should not call Client activity by creating new instance (new Client()). Activity should be started using startActivity(intent) only

Comment: I did not understand the reason?

Comment: Actually i have an activity named new activity where the server and client will be responding , so to implement the client class , am i not supposed to call the client class? how will intent help me out with that?

Comment: Yes, Client is extending Activity, If you create an activity instance by yourself, then the window for that activity won't be created, So you cannot use findViewById method, which queries the Window which is not available and leads the app to crash

Comment: oh okay....now i understand this (y) ... thanks for the help :)

Comment: When you create a new object for activity class, activity will not be loaded and **EditText ip** will be null. Java class object cannot get the edittext value, it can be loaded only when activity is launched.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set your layout to the activity so you can bind views. Like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Second, i am realy confused what are you trying to do in SMessage() method. I think you should do some research about application logic, starting activity and activity lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a Service for communication between client and server. It will run in background but you can communicate with server via it. If you start a new activity it will stop your current activity and put it in backstack. Your current activity will not be accessible from the new activity. And you can't run two activity at the same time. So use a service to handle client-server communication and change your client view according to the response received from server via service. It will be a good practice